# Inconsistent error while storing a darray into a Shape

Tags: hacklang

I have a shape like this

```
const type TFileInfo = shape(
        'displayName' => string,
        'givenName' => string,
        'jobTitle' => string,
        'businessPhones' => vec<string>
    );
    private Person::TFileInfo $person;
```

Now my constructor of the class looks like so

```
public function __construct(string $apiresponse) { // instance method
    $json = \json_decode($response, /* associative = */ true);
    TypeAssert\matches<self::TFileInfo>($json);
    $this->person = $json; //OFFENDING LINE
    $this->person['businessPhones1'] = "";
}
```

Now strangely the above code does not throw any error .

If I remove the offending line , then the last line throws a compile time error **Expected nothing because the field 'businessPhones1' is not defined in this shape type, and this shape type does not allow unknown fields**

What am I missing here ? Is there a better way to assign an API response to a typed variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypeAssert\matches` doesn't prove that its argument is the type you specified, in contrast to the behavior of some other built-ins like `is_null` which are special-cased in the typechecker. Instead, it coerces the argument and returns it, so you need to move your standalone call to the assignment, i.e. `$this->person = TypeAssert\matches<self::TFileInfo>($json);`.

You might have expected a type error from the `$this->person = $json` assignment then, but in fact `json_decode` and some other unsafe built-in PHP functions are special-cased by the typechecker to be bottom types (convertible to anything) so they could be usable at all before type-assert. It remains this way today: see [its type definition in the HHVM source](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/1c726c18f34243429acfdd0b96b88fe2b517afdb/hphp/hack/hhi/stdlib/builtins_json.hhi#L65), probably for compatibility.

---

One other interesting point about this case is that `$this->person = $json` coerces `$this->person` to a bottom type as well downstream of the binding. To my understanding, this is a specific behavior of the Hack typechecker to do this for a single level of property nesting, yet it preserves the types for properties of properties (the second example `has_error`):

```
<?hh // strict
class Box<T> { public function __construct(public T $v) {} }
function no_error<T>(Box<int> $arg): T {
    $arg->v = json_decode('');
    return $arg->v;
}
function has_error<T>(Box<Box<int>> $arg): T {
    $arg->v->v = json_decode('');
    return $arg->v->v;
}
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly $this->person = $json; tells the compiler that $person can accept anything not just shape and hence the person['businessPhones1'] is accepted ?

Comment: That's a good question. It seems that `$this->person` becomes a bottom type for the rest of the function. I've added an edit to explain this.